# Writing a LaTeXParser in Java, conceptually attacking

Tags: java, parsing, latex, stack

Alright so I have to write a LaTeXParser in java, I'm going to be taking in a file much like this one below and reading it for validity and errors. Now I am not looking for help really or code but more of a conceptual understanding, how to attack the problem. I am going to be using Stacks to store the blocks and make sure everything is sorted properly. So my question to you is, how to handle it?

For example, Should I begin by getting all the "\begin{*_*}" and putting them in a stack and then pop them with their corresponding "\end{}"? I was wondering using a String based case switch system that, when particular strings were found, would perform the actions necessary based on that string, on my stack.

Or maybe 2 Stacks that cancel each other out, all the \begins in one and the \ends in another and has their {*_*_} match up, I start poping them out and what not.

So yeah, just wondering what the bright minds of SOF had to say about how I should be thinking about this problem and how to deal with it. Thanks for your input!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\begin{document}
    {\Large \begin{center} Homework Problems \end{center}}\begin{itemize}\item\end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
            \item Prove: For all sets $A$ and $B$, $(A - B) \cup
                    (A \cap B) = A$.
                    \begin{proof}
                            \begin{align}
                                    & (A - B) \cup (A \cap B) && \\
                                    & = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B) && \text{by
                                    Alternate Definition of Set Difference} \\
                                    & = A \cap (B^c \cup B) && \text{by Distributive Law} \\
                                    & = A \cap (B \cup B^c) && \text{by Commutative Law} \\
                                    & = A \cap U && \text{by Union with the Complement Law} \\
                                    & = A && \text{by Intersection with $U$ Law}
                            \end{align}
                    \end{proof}
            \item If $n = 4k + 3$, does 8 divide $n^2 - 1$?
                    \begin{proof}
                            Let $n = 4k + 3$ for some integer $k$. Then
                            \begin{align}
                                    n^2 - 1 & = (4k + 3)^2 - 1 \\
                                    & = 16k^2 + 24k + 9 - 1 \\
                                    & = 16k^2 + 24k + 8 \\
                                    & = 8(2k^2 + 3k + 1) \text{,}
                            \end{align}
                            which is certainly divisible by 8.
                    \end{proof}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Lol I think everyone is overthinking this wayyyyyy too much, I am not looking for anything that recognizes and compiles code, or actually performs the actions of the LATEX language via this file. I simply want to be able to write up a text file, like the one above, have my program open it, read it, and say "hey! this would work because every block that begins also ends!" Or "hey theres an error on line 10!" Nothing more, nothing less. Just a simple validator/error checker that uses Stacks to contain the blocks and then pops them when the end is found and so on. Again I AM NOT LOOKING FOR CODE OR HANDOUTS! All I would like is some good ideas and methods for attacking this problem, maybe some pseudo code structuring at best!

For example...I was thinking of having this all contained in 1 class, in my main, and making a Stack that would hold all of the Strings in the file that were coded like such " \begin{**_*} " then when I found the corresponding " \end{***} " just popping it out and check it off a list or something. If every beginning block is popped by the end of my run through the file, I have a valid .txt file.

Comment: What, a full LaTeX parser?

Comment: Huge problem.  Closing as not constructive - we cannot design an application this large for you in a constructive fashion.

Comment: No I am not looking for anyone to make me anything, just brainstorm, toss around good ideas.

Comment: Have you tried http://texlipse.sourceforge.net?

Comment: Do you want a full compatible LaTeX parser, able to correctly parse existing files? Or just something which parses a subset used in your own LaTeX files?

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine but not on SO where questions are meant to be answered, not discussed

Answer (score 3):

Trying to roll your own parser is a big task. There are a number of [Parser Generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) that take some of the busy work out of the task. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is a popular one for java.

One of the first things you're going to need to do is find out what kind of language latex is? More complicated languages like C++ can't be parsed with the same kinds of parsers that you can use for a more regular language like forth.

The following [Jules Bean post](http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg09966.html) leads me to think that latex is harder to parse than most programming languages.

> I'm pretty sure it's not an LALR language.  It's context dependent and is capable of modifying it's own syntax.  I think it is probably technical impossible to parse without actually executing the macros.  I.e. you need a TeX state machine to parse it in full generality.
>
> 'well-behaved' LaTeX is probably LALR, though.

Comment: JavaCC is more simple than ANTLR.